# python plotly: change y axis range without changing markers size

Tags: python, statistics, plotly, visualization

I created a rug plot using scatter plot.
This is my code:

```
 fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = group_sample_clean,
    y = [0]*len(group_sample_clean),
    mode = 'markers',
    marker_color="lightskyblue",
    marker_line_width=2, 
    marker_size=30,
    marker_symbol = 'line-ns',
    showlegend = False
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = single_sample,
    y = [0],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker_color = 'orange',
    marker_symbol = 'star',
    marker_size = 40,
    showlegend = False
    ))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, automargin=True, showticklabels=False)
fig.update_layout(title_text=f'{feature} samples in {key} in {age_group}')
fig.show()
```

The graph looks like that:
[image]

I want it to look like that:
[image]

any conventional way of changing the axis's range didn't work because the markers' (black lines) size change automatically to fit these dimensions...

Any ideas what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it -
added

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=250,
    margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ))
```